# Flutter Open Multiple Drawers

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, drawer

Im looking for a way to open multiple drawers in flutter to display different data depending on which list tile I clicked.
So I have a ListView which has multiple ListTiles - Asset Code, Asset Name etc.
I want to display different data inside the drawer itself depending on which ListTile I have clicked so if I clicked the asset code tile I would get asset code data and so on.
I was wanting to display all of this inside drawers only but cannot understand how to do so; Any help is appreciated!
This is my code:

```
List filterType = ['Asset Code', 'Name', 'Description', 'Location'];

class FilterTerms extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterTerms({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterTerms> createState() => _FilterTermsState();
}

class _FilterTermsState extends State<FilterTerms> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Scaffold(
        endDrawer: filterCodeData(context),
        body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[900]),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'First Drawer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: drawerCodeData(context, filterCodeData(context)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: drawerNameData(context, filterNameData(context)),
            )]);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Drawer drawerCodeData(BuildContext context, Widget drawerName) {
  return Drawer(
      child: Scaffold(
    endDrawer: filterCodeData(context),
    body: ListTile(
      title: Text(filterType[0]),
      onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
      },
    ),
  ));
}

Drawer drawerNameData(BuildContext context, Widget drawerName) {
  return Drawer(
      child: Scaffold(
        endDrawer: filterNameData(context),
        body: ListTile(
          title: Text(filterType[1]),
          onTap: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ));
}

Widget filterCodeData(BuildContext context) => const Drawer(
      child: Center(child: Text('Code Data')),
    );

Widget filterNameData(BuildContext context) => const Drawer(
  child: Center(child: Text('Name Data')),
);
```

FilterTerms is also being called in a drawer in a previous widget.
Thanks!